# I need to convert string to date in python

Tags: python, string

I need to convert string to date type.What should I do?

My string is "04 Oct 2019". I need to convert to date type "04/10/2019".
Note:You can't ignore 0

Comment: I have tried many ways

Comment: if some one downvote question they should give the reason. Its not professional way

Answer (score 0):

```
import calendar

def convert_str_to_date(s):
    l = s.split()
    l[1] = "{0:02d}".format(list(calendar.month_abbr).index(l[1]))
    return "/".join(l)

print(convert_str_to_date("04 Oct 2019"))
```

It won't ignore 0 as `"{0:02d}".format`

Comment: Thank you so much.I thought there may be a API in python.